# Request body undefined in controller Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, next.js

I have a problem with my controller when I'm writing console.log(req); I have all the content of the request body but when I write console.log(req.body); is undefined. I'm trying to write my Portfolio with Next.js React and Express.

This is my server index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const routes = require('../routes');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


// SERVICE
const authService = require('./services/auth');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = routes.getRequestHandler(app);
const config = require('./config');

const portfolioRoutes = require('./routes/portfolio');

const secretData = [
{   id: '1',
    title: 'Secret Data',
    description: 'plans for build something !'
},
{   
    id: '2',
    title: 'Secret Data2',
    description: 'plans for build something2 !'
}
]


//MONGODB
mongoose.connect(config.DB_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(() => {
console.log("Db connected");

}).catch(err => console.log(err));



app.prepare()
.then(() => {
const server = express();
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
server.use('/api/v1/portfolio', portfolioRoutes);

server.get('/api/v1/secret', authService.checkJWT, (req,res) => {
    return res.json(secretData);

})

server.get('/api/v1/ownersite', authService.checkJWT, authService.checkRole('siteOwner'),
    (req,res) => {
    return res.json(secretData);

})

server.get('*', jsonParser,(req,res) => {
    return handle(req,res);
})

server.use(function (err, req, res, next){
    if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        res.status(401).send({title: `Invalid token...`});
    }
});

server.use(handle).listen(3000, (err) => {
    if(err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
})

}).catch((ex) => {
console.error(ex.stack)
process.exit(1);
})
```

This is my routes :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const portfolioCtrl = require('../controllers/portfolio');
const authService = require('../services/auth');

router.route('').get(authService.checkJWT, authService.checkRole('siteOwner'),       
portfolioCtrl.getPortfolio);
router.route('').post(authService.checkJWT, authService.checkRole('siteOwner'),     
portfolioCtrl.savePortfolio);
router.route('/:id').patch(authService.checkJWT, authService.checkRole('siteOwner'),     
portfolioCtrl.updatePortfolio);
router.route('/:id').delete(authService.checkJWT, authService.checkRole('siteOwner'),     
portfolioCtrl.deletePortfolio);

module.exports = router;
```

This is my Controller:

```
savePortfolio: (res, req) => {
    console.log(req);
    const portfolioData = req.body;
    const portfolio = new Portfolio(portfolioData);
    portfolio.save((err, createdPortfolio) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(422).send(err);
        }
        return res.json(createdPortfolio);
    })
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express route's callback function takes the parameters in the following order:

> `(req, res, next) =>{...}`
>
> - req, the request object.
> - res, the response object.
> - next, indicating the next middleware function (Optional)

`savePortfolio: (res, req) => {...}` has the order wrong. That is why `req.body` would be `undefined`.

Correction: `savePortfolio: (req, res) => {...}`

Comment: Hey that's great, is working thanks a lot man so small thing and I lost 2h ...